# How to make this toroid-like mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, geometry

I'm talking about the stack of toroids in this post.  My first attempt is on the left. I literally stacked up a bunch of toruses, overlapping them to create a "solid". It renders well enough.  I was dissatisfied with the number of faces, however.  Feels like bad style to me, and I don't like the idea each of these is a separate mesh.

Enter take 2, the one on the right.  This one is a cylinder. I put 40+ loop-cuts around it.  I selected every 4th loop cut and scaled. These became the high point of each toroid.  Then I grabbed the same loop cuts and the ones adjacent, and scaled these until I had the shape you see below.  It's a single mesh and feels better.  However, to make it, I had to laboriously select dozens of loop cuts and eyeball them into a toroid.  Took a long time.  I wanted to add a few more of the toroids to the bottom, but I couldn't see how to do it except by duplicating the mesh and shrinkwrapping the duplicated section to the bottom. It works but it isn't perfect. What a pain.

How would a non-beginner bang this mesh out without it being such a manual and fiddly process?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Never used an array modifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a Torus in *Object Mode* under *Add > Mesh > Torus*

[image]

Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>1</kbd> to go into *Vertex Select Mode* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle into *X-Ray Mode* then follow this GIF animation to select the top and bottom part of vertices and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Vertices*. Then hover over the inner remaining part of the Torus and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select it, and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Vertices*. Then use the [`Array Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) and the *Merge* option to fuse and stack multiple torus meshes on top of each other that get merged into one mesh.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this today.  It seems much better than what I did.

Comment: This worked great. I never knew about selecting "linked" vertices.